# use localizable in telerik upload control

Tags: model-view-controller, telerik

I use this code but,nothing change, i still have the "select" button and "remove" button. Is it possible to localize telerik upload?

```
Html.Telerik().Upload()
                .Name("PostedAvatar")
                .Multiple(false)
                .Async(async => async
                     .Save("SaveAvatar", "UploadPhotoFields")
                     .Remove("RemoveAvatar", "UploadPhotoFields")
                     .AutoUpload(true)
                      ).Localizable("uk")
...
```

using of

```
@Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Globalization(true)
```

don't influetnt on upload control.

Tanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that you have the proper localization files for the language you are selecting as well. The Telerik Extensions all use resource files when it comes to localization, and there is actually a documentation article (found [right here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-upload-localization.html)) which explains in more detail the exact steps needed to properly localize the upload component.